# remove rows where columns contain only NaN or Zero

Tags: python, pandas, subset, drop

I have the following list of dataframes. I need to remove from each df the rows that include **only** the values NaN **or** Zero. I cannot change all Zeros to NaN, as in other columns, they have a valid meaning rather than reflecting missing/not a number info. Ideally, i would like to combine the commands in this sort of format [x.dropna(axis=0, how='all') for x in dfs]. thank you!

**data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1,2,0,4,5,6], 
                         'a': [41,41,0,43,40,41], 
                         'b': [21,20,0,19,23,23],
                         'c': [0,0,0,0,43,0],
                         'd': [12,11,0,0,0,0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[0,2,0,4,5,6], 
                         'a': [0,41,0,43,40,41], 
                         'b': ['NaN',20,'NaN',19,23,23],
                         'c': [0,0,0,0,43,0],
                         'd': [0,11,0,0,0,0]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':[1,2,'NaN','NaN',5,0], 
                         'a': [41,41,0,43,40,0], 
                         'b': [21,20,0,19,23,0],
                         'c': [0,0,0,0,43,0],
                         'd': [12,11,0,0,0,0]})

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
```

**expected output**

```
[   id   a   b   c   d
 0   1  41  21   0  12
 1   2  41  20   0  11
 2   4  43  19   0   0
 3   5  40  23  43   0
 4   6  41  23   0   0,
    id   a   b   c   d
 0   2  41  20   0  11
 1   4  43  19   0   0
 2   5  40  23  43   0
 3   6  41  23   0   0,
     id   a   b   c   d
 0    1  41  21   0  12
 1    2  41  20   0  11
 2  NaN  43  19   0   0
 3    5  40  23  43   0
 4    0   0   0   0   0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace 0 to missing values, but better is removed original DataFrames by this repalced one with tested all rows if exist at least one non `NaN` value in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
dfs = [x[x.replace(0, np.nan).notna().any(axis=1)] for x in dfs]

print (dfs)
[   id   a   b   c   d
0   1  41  21   0  12
1   2  41  20   0  11
3   4  43  19   0   0
4   5  40  23  43   0
5   6  41  23   0   0,    id   a     b   c   d
1   2  41  20.0   0  11
3   4  43  19.0   0   0
4   5  40  23.0  43   0
5   6  41  23.0   0   0,     id   a   b   c   d
0  1.0  41  21   0  12
1  2.0  41  20   0  11
3  NaN  43  19   0   0
4  5.0  40  23  43   0]
```

If there are only positive values is possible test if `sum` is not `0`:

```
dfs = [x[x.sum(axis=1).ne(0)] for x in dfs]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other options

```
dfs = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
dfs["sum"] = dfs.sum(axis=1)
dfs = dfs.drop(dfs[dfs["sum"] == 0].index)
dfs
```

Output

```
    id  a   b   c   d   sum
1   2   41  20  0   11  104
3   4   43  19  0   0   86
4   5   40  23  43  0   166
1   2   41  20  0   11  104
3   4   43  19  0   0   86
4   5   40  23  43  0   166
1   2   41  20  0   11  104
3   NaN     43  19  0   0   86
4   5   40  23  43  0   166
```

Comment: If you had -x and x (for example 1) with a 50/50 distribution in a column you would eliminate data with this approach. I'm looking for a better way to sum a column containing 0 and NaN but I want to make sure that no other values make the sum() go to zero. I guess the abs() value would work.